# extract numerical values from string after dash (-)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have string value like this Rs.100 - Rs.250 Now I want only 250 from this string.

I tried this but it's not getting output

```
var result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);
```

UPDATE

```
string result = price.Text;
string[] final_result = result.Split('.');
dynamic get_result = final_result(1).ToString();
price.Text = final_result.ToString;
```

Comment: I assume that's giving you a `result` of `" Rs.250"`, right? I'm not sure why you thought that would work?

Comment: The current code will give you `Rs.250` remove `Rs.` from the result, it will be fine then

Comment: You can try like that: `var result = str.Split('.').Reverse().First();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
    string str = "Rs.100-Rs.250";
        var result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('-') + 1);


        String[] final_result = result.Split('.');
        var get_result = final_result[1].ToString();
```

this will get 250 as you wanted.

Comment: make it a string like this get_result.toString();

Answer (score 1):

Try this code after getting the result of Rs.250.

```
var data = Regex.Match(result, @"\d+").Value;
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for helping the others. Formatting a good answer will help people to understand you more and also will help you get vote up

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var result = ("Rs.100 - Rs.250").Split('-').LastOrDefault().Split('.').LastOrDefault();
```